# Not work screen.unlockOrientation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have user Ionic v1 and AngularJS (v1). I have used [cordova-plugin-screen-orientation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) and lock one page using below method.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  $scope.changeOriantationLandspace = function() {
    screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
  }
  $scope.changeOriantationPortrait = function() {
    screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
  }
}
```

It's working fine now, but how to unlock the screen? Can you please tell me the method.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Apparently you are using an old version of the plugin. I suppose this will work for you. Next time you downvote an answer, at least explain why

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation):

> The plugin adds the following to the screen object (window.screen):

```
// lock the device orientation
screen.orientation.lock('portrait');

// unlock the orientation
screen.orientation.unlock();
```

But it seems like you are using an [old version](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/tree/Release1-4-3) of the plugin, so you need to use:

```
// lock the device orientation
screen.lockOrientation('portrait')

// unlock the orientation
screen.unlockOrientation()
```